# Explode date in php

Tags: php, datetime, explode

I have a date in my sql with the following format:

20150426

I want to convert it to format 26/05/2015 into a variable.

Which is the best way to do it?

Can I do it with explode?

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: `strtotime` and `date`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do in this manner----

```
<?php
    $nextBse = date('d/m/Y',strtotime(20150426));
echo $nextBse;
?>
```

Output:--  26/04/2015

Answer (score 1):

Please follow this method

edit:
d means "day"
m means "month"
Y means "year"
so the format of date will be d/m/Y
and we have a date to convert a new format but our data is not full data

like day/month/year/hour/minute/second 
there are day,month,year
and we need to convert full date
so we use strtotime($ourdate);

```
$dt="20150426";
echo date('d/m/Y',strtotime($dt));
```